# Ssis use an object variable for a condition

Tags: oracle, ssis

I have an execute sql task that assign the the result of a sql task into many of my variables with a result set. It only works if I use the object type for the type of my variables. Then after that, I want to use those variables to set a constraint with an expression.By ssis does not allow object type variable for these operation. Is there any ways to fix that problem? here is what my sql statement is:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) as s5 from random_table where rownum < 100) as S5,
(SELECT COUNT(*)  as s6 from random_Table_2 where rownum < 100) as s6 from dual
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Data types cannot change within SSIS, unless the base type is Object. However, you can't *do* anything, expression-wise, with Variables of type Object.

General purpose approach then is to use a Foreach Enumerator to *shred* the result set. For each row in that Object variable, you can address the individual column elements and assign *those* into strongly typed Variables (which you then use in an Precedent Constraint).

Specific purpose for this question, you change your Execute SQL Task that is currently populating the variable of type Object. Your supplied query is only ever going to return 1 row of data (2 columns but that's arbitrary). In this special case, you can modify the `ResultSet` of an Execute SQL Task to be `SingleRow` (instead of `None` or `Full` as you currently have it set). With a SingleRow property set, instead of dumping everything into a single variable, you will assign strongly typed SSIS Variables into the specific columns.

Examples

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28503036/181965
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24389822/181965
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9162133/181965
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21762589/181965

Comment: I haave already set my property to singleRow and in the resultset tab, I then assign my parameter like s6 to a single variable.But it will only accept object type variables. I don't understanfd how to put them into int variable for examples.

Comment: Your variable is of type Object. It's always going to work. You need to change the Variable's data type to align with the type coming from Oracle, probably Int32 or Int64